# How to upsert records from Azure Synapse dedicated SQL Pool table Dataverse table in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataverse

I want to move data regularly from Synapse SQL pool to dynamics 365 dataverse, Everytime I do that I need to truncate the table in dataverse and run the pipeline in ADF, instead of truncating everytime I found we can do upsert to the dataverse table.

Table in Synapse SQL Pool: Recommendation_All_Progress
Table in Dataverse: cr726_progressreporttest
Column set as Alternate Key in Dataverse: 'cr726_contactid'

I need to update records based on the above mentioned column.

If the data for that column is in source and in the dataverse, it needs to updated in dataverse, else it needs to inserted as a new row.

I couldn't figure out how can I do this in ADF data flow.
Can someone give me the correct method to do this?

If the above provided details is insufficient, please let me know.

I have tried it in data flow, but got this error:
[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4zBL.png)

can anyone clarify the error?

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, create a pipeline and add a copy data activity.

On the source tab, create a dataset (and linked service if you don't have one already) of type Azure Synapse analytics connected to your source table.

On the sink tab create a dataset (and linked service if you don't have one already) of type Dynamic CRM linked to the entity you want to update.

configure the sink tab you use upsert, and set the alternate key name to "cr726_contactid":
[image: sink]

Comment: Hey @Chen Hirsh, thank you for your repsonse, I couldn't able to do it with pipeline because, it says there is no entity in dataverse. Even though I had it there. So I tried it with data flow, but I got an error. I have edited the post above to include the error screenshot, can please help me on that?

Thanks.